# How useful are bounties for this specific Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I was thinking of setting up a bounty for my question on [pointers](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/what-are-the-advantages-of-allowing-users-to-directly-handle-memory-addresses-wi) so I could get some more answers. However, from my current understanding of bounties, I realized that they are awarded on the answer seen to be best by the awarder. However, for a site like this, where there may be no one correct or right answer, bounties may not be as useful in encouraging more answers for a certain question as it is less likely for one single answer to be best. Would this be a problem for this site and what can be done to make sure bounties are actually effective?

Comment: On [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), bounties are often awarded *after* the answer has been posted as a reward. I think this we could also reward good answers with bounties on this site.

Comment: Not *all* questions here are like "pros-cons" or "multiple-approaches"; plenty can have objectively correct answers. Even for more subjective questions, when you create a bounty you can write a message saying what kind of answer you're looking to encourage.

Comment: Myself I haven't found bounties to be very useful at all as my questions are not answered because of the obscurity of the answer. I think perhaps bounties are best suited to questions that are easy to answer but have not attracted enough attention (or post answer rewards as mentioned).

Answer (score 5):

Here are some use cases:

1. You like an answer but want more depth in an area. If the answer you like is edited to have that depth, then give it the bounty. Otherwise, a new answer may deal exclusively with that area and you can award the bounty to it
2. To draw more attention. In that case award the bounty to the more complete, through, useful, etc answer.
3. You can always reward an answer you really like

In general, award the one that helped **you** the most. If they helped you equally then I personally award the highest voted and it helped a bunch of other people too.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the bounty is to encourage answers by awarding more rep. I wouldn't think to deeply about it. Set the bounty, and award the bounty in whatever way you want.

- You can choose not to award it manually, in which case the system has conditions for automatic awarding.
- You can choose to award it to the new answer that you think is the most useful / deserving (how you determine that is up to you. It's your rep on the line, after all)
- You can choose to award it to any answer (including pre-existing ones) that you think is the most useful or deserving.